# This error comes when i use jasperPHP in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, jasper-reports

Your report has an error and couldn't be processed!
Try to output the command using the function `output();` and run it manually in the console.

This is my code:

```
    $jasper = new JasperPHP;

    //jasper ready to call
    $jasper->compile(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/Simple_Blue.jrxml')->execute();

        // Process a Jasper file to PDF and RTF (you can use directly the .jrxml)
    $jasper->process(
        __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/Simple_Blue.jasper',
        false,
        array("pdf", "rtf"),
        array("php_version" => phpversion())
    )->execute();

    // List the parameters from a Jasper file.
    $array = $jasper->list_parameters(
        __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/Simple_Blue.jasper'
    )->execute();

    Yii::$app->response->sendFile(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/cossou/jasperphp/examples/Simple_Blue.pdf');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone got the same error first of all this error comes if there is a error in your code.
my error was that i haven't given the argument list in the right order for the function process.
Now it is working fine!!